# How to use the old progress bar in Java?

Tags: java, windows, progress-bar

So, I've seen this in a few places:

[image: Progress bar]

And as far as I know, that's the really old progress bar that Windows used to use. However, regardless of its outdated look, this would fit perfectly in my program. I'm wondering how could I get this into my Java program instead of the current green progress bar with a white foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this repository:

https://github.com/JaydipZala/Custom-Progressbar

This is my result:
[image]

You can see the demo in here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.SonhnLab.AntiDog2

Hope it help!